# Files such as com.apple.finder or com.apple.dock

Tags: macos, library

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, from a Software or Hardware stand point prospective,

Using Terminal, I discovered once in a while, files that are named for example com.apple.finder or com.apple.dock etc.

What does it mean? Why they are named com.apple.*

Answer (score 1):

It's called ‘[reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation)’ and is widely used for naming packages/etc.

> The suggested convention for generating unique package names is merely a way to piggyback a package naming convention on top of an existing, widely known unique name registry instead of having to create a separate registry for package names.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html
- [What is the significance of the reverse domain name for java package structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475168/what-is-the-significance-of-the-reverse-domain-name-for-java-package-structure)